# Download roles are not working on Read the Docs

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm trying to get a download link to work in Read the Docs using reStructuredText (reST) and Sphinx. In the reST documentation for the [download role](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#referencing-downloadable-files) the example to provide a download link is given as

```py
.. only:: builder_html

   See :download:`this example script <../example.py>`.
```

When making the html source locally the links appear, but when using a GitHub linked project on Read the Docs, they do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/4765#issuecomment-431927720) Read the Docs uses its own builder called `readthedocs`. Thus, to include the download links you must also include this builder. For example

```
.. only:: builder_html or readthedocs

   See :download:`this example script <../example.py>`.
```